# How to group post "elements" in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I would like to subdivide my post elements in sections, by *somehow* creating multiple elements and then use them in liquid.

For example, I tried to put this in the post front matter:

```
element: some text
element: some other text
element: even more text
```

But if I try to reference those in liquid:

```
{% for elemento in post.element %}
      {{ elemento  }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then only the last "element" is considered.

This makes me think that you can't have multiple variables with the same name and cycle through them, because Jekyll would only read the last one and ignore the previous ones with the same name.

*I don't want to use different variable names (as in element1, element2, and so on) because each post would have a different number of elements.*

What would be a way to achieve that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an **elements array** in your front matter.

```
elements :
 - valueOne
 - valueTwo
```

or

```
elements: [valueOne, valueTwo]
```

Then, you can loop in **elements** :

From inside your post or a layout

```
<ul>
{% for element in page.elements %}
  <li>{{ element }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

From inside a `site.posts` loop :

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% for element in posts.elements %}
    <li>{{ element }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly and was what I was looking for. I just had to replace "page" with "post".

Comment: also, I got to use the variable element.element instead of just "element" otherwhise that'd look like this: {"element"=>"text" }. 

I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more precise. You can use page or post, it depends on the context. And, if you need to use `element.element`, it's that you have an `elements: [ element: value1, element: value2]` array, and you have the same problem with last value overriding former one. Appropriate use is `elements: [valueOne, valueTwo]` with quoted values or not.